# VBA insert a row to table with format like below

Tags: vba, excel

I want to insert a row to the first line of table through macro .
my code like this :

```
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("MeanArea").ListRows.Add _
        Position:=1, _
        alwaysinsert:=True
```

But the format of the inserted row was follow the table header ,what can I do to make the inserted row format same as the rows in table area?
[image: screenshot]
As you can see the first row was just inserted using the macro ,I want the font color be white not red

Anyone pls help.

Comment: Your code works for me...

Comment: it worked ,but the format of inserted row will be same as table header ,not refer the rows below ,my table area format is not same as table header

Comment: Which Excel version are you using? Can I see a screenshot of the table with the newly inserted row?

Comment: Hi @Rout ,you can see the screenshot in my new answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to change your code with this

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("MeanArea").ListRows.Add (1)
```

The above code is to insert a row above row 1 in the table.

---

### Edit

This works fine and suits your need

```
With Worksheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("MeanArea")
    .ListRows.Add 1
    .ListRows(2).Range.Copy
    .ListRows(1).Range.PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
End With
Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

Comment: @SiddharthRout Dunno. But it works fine on my machine

Comment: it worked ,but the format of inserted row will be same as table header ,not refer the rows below

Comment: @zaza.wang Well, by saying *the code works* means the format row is the same as the other rows in the body table, not the header's.

Comment: @秀 Actually it will be same as the header format ,you can change your header format such as font color and run the macro again then you will see...

Comment: @zaza.wang Have a look my edited answer. It should work

Comment: @SiddharthRout I edited my answer and it works fine now. It seems the default font color in the OP' worksheet is red, that's why the inserted row is also red.

Comment: @SiddharthRout Thank you. Your compliment means a lot to me :)